# Issue with anchor tag in Html to OpenXML convertor

Tags: html, openxml-sdk

I am using https://html2openxml.codeplex.com/ for converting HTML to OpenXML and then creating a word document.

It works fine for other things except that when I add and anchor tag to the html. It throws the error stating that the Word document has unreadable content.

Any help on this will be much appreciated

Comment: could you give an example of your code/html, a fiddle would be great

Comment: var htmlData = "Looks how cool is <font size='x-large'><b>Open Xml</b></font>."
   + "Now with <font color='red'><u>HtmlToOpenXml</u></font>, it nevers been so easy to convert html.<p>"
   + "If you like it, add me a rating on <a title='codeplex' href='http://notesforhtml2openxml.codeplex.com'>codeplex</a>  </p <hr>";
   HtmlConverter converter = new HtmlConverter(documentPart);
   converter.ExcludeLinkAnchor = true;
   converter.RefreshStyles();
      var paragraphs = converter.Parse(htmlData);